# Transport.send(message) throwing NoSuchProviderException

Tags: java, eclipse

I am creating a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse Kepler under Windows which will send email to some address. I have added the "**activation.jar**" & "**javax.mail-1.5.1.jar**" in my lib folder. The problem is, first time when I ran it, it was working fine. But after few days when tried to rest again, it is showing the following Exception

```
javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: smtp
at javax.mail.Session.getService(Session.java:800)
at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:736)
at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:676)
at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:656)
at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:713)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:248)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at com.uks.pms.common.mail.dao.MailDAO.sendEmail(MailDAO.java:183)
at com.uks.pms.user.attendance.action.ATUpdateAction.update(ATUpdateAction.java:188)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
...................................................
```

The method I've written to perform the action is as follows-

```
public void sendEmail(MailBean mailConfig, String fromID, String toID,
        String ccTo, StringBuffer mailContent) throws AddressException,
        SendFailedException, MessagingException, Exception {

    javax.mail.Session session = null;
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = null;

    try {
        session = getSession(mailConfig);
        mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
        mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromID));
        mimeMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress(toID));
        mimeMessage.setSubject(MailUtil.MAIL_CONTENT_SUBJECT);
        if (!(ccTo == null || ccTo.isEmpty())) {
            mimeMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC,
                    new InternetAddress(ccTo));
        }
        mimeMessage.setText(mailContent.toString());
        mimeMessage.setContent(mailContent.toString(),
                MailUtil.MAIL_CONTENT_TYPE);
        Transport.send(mimeMessage);
        System.out
                .println("IF YOU ARE SEEING THIS MESSAGE THEN IT MEANS YOU HAVE SUCCESSFULLY SENT THE EMAIL");
    } finally {
        System.gc();
    }
}

private javax.mail.Session getSession(MailBean mailConfig) throws Exception {
    Properties properties = null;
    javax.mail.Session session = null;

    try {
        properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.setProperty(MailUtil.KEY_MAIL_SMTP_PORT,
                mailConfig.getPortNo());
        properties.setProperty(MailUtil.KEY_MAIL_SMTP_HOST,
                mailConfig.getMailServer());

        session = javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
    } finally {
        System.gc();
    }
    return session;
}
```

where the *port number is 587* & *host is 172.51.10.40* in a network. I am using `hmailserver` as the Mail Server without any authentication & all the firewall setting are set properly. I could not understand where the problem occurred. Please give some solution. If any other information is required, kindly let me know that.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any other versions of same jar in your classpath? Sorry I deleted my previous comment as smtp.jar required in earlier versions of javax.mail

Comment: No. Only the mentioned two jars are added. Even it is working fine when I am running it as simple Java program. But not working in web project.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are running this in a servlet container you could be running into [Bug 6668 -skip unusable Store and Transport classes](https://kenai.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6668).  If you can, upgrade to JavaMail 1.5.3.  Otherwise, change your session creation to the following:

```
    final ClassLoader ccl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(Session.class.getClassLoader());
    try {
        session = javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
    } finally {
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(ccl);
    }
```

It is a good idea to [fix the common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#commonmistakes) in your code.